# how to delete auto closed brackets in VSCode extetnsion Completion?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I register `[[` as the completion trigger word, VSCode will auto generate `]]` for `[[`,

My completion want to delete the `[[]]`.

For example:

when user type `[[`,

user may type some filter text,

the final result will be `[xxx](/xxx)`

I tried `additionalTextEdits` to delete `[[]]`, but when user type some filter text, the position will be wrong.

```js
item.insertText = `[${title}](/${relativePath})`;

const start = position.character - 2;
item.additionalTextEdits = [
        vscode.TextEdit.delete(
          new vscode.Range(position.line, start, position.line, start + 4)
        ),
];
```

Comment: you can analyze the line your completion prefix is on and adjust the range of text that needs to be replaced

Comment: @rioV8 I don't get it. can you give some code examples?

Answer (score 0):

Solve this by using `command`, completion can add a `command` param, which can do something when completion complete.

```
vscode.commands.registerCommand(
  'foam-vscode.delete-wiki-link-end-brackets',
  () => {
    const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
    if (editor) {
      const current = editor.selection.active;
      editor.edit(editBuilder => {
        editBuilder.delete(
          new vscode.Range(
            current.line,
            current.character,
            current.line,
            current.character + 2
          )
        );
      });
      return;
    }
  }
);
```